# haskell : how to draw some pixels (side effects) using gtk and the function map

Tags: loops, haskell, side-effects

I am trying to learn [gtk2hs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk), an API wich allows haskell programs to use windows, menus, toolbars and graphs.

I want to draw the Mandelbrot set, so I began to write the stuff, but I am stuck at the end, namely when I have to use side effects to draw each point of the Mandelbrot set.

The datas are : I have a canvas (a drawing area) of 300px * 200px, and a function `mandelbrot :: Float -> Float -> Bool`, whose output is true if the point is in the mandelbrot set, and false otherwise.

the work to achieve is : for each pixel (width : 0 to 300, height : 0 to 200), transform the coordinates to a range of [-2..2]*[-2..2], call the mandelbrot function, and if the result is true, call a function of the package [Cairo](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cairo) which draws the point. (The function is [`C.rectangle a b 1 1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cairo-0.13.1.1/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Cairo.html#v:rectangle).)

My try:

```
example :: Double -> Double -> C.Render ()
example width height = do
  setSourceRGB 0 0 0
  setLineWidth 1

  let 
    affiche a b = do 
      if (mandelbrot a b) then 
        C.rectangle a b 1 1
        return()
      return ()

    colonnes = [0..299]
    lignes = [0..199]
  in 
    map (\t -> t/300*4-2) colonnes
    map (\t -> t/200*4-2) lignes
    map affiche (zip (colonnes,lignes))
    stroke            -- it displays the changes on the screen
```

It triggers the error:
- at the second `return`:

```
Error: Parse error: return
```

thanks

EDIT:
Thanks a lot for your answer.
I greatly improved my program, but I still have errors.

here is the latest version:

```
affiche :: Double -> Double -> Render()
affiche a b = when (mandelbrot a b) $ C.rectangle a b 1 1

colonnes = [ t/300.0*4.0-2.0 | t<-[0.0..299.0] ]
lignes = [ t/200.0*4.0-2.0 | t<-[0.0..199.0] ]


example :: Double -> Double -> C.Render ()
example width height = do
    setSourceRGB 0 0 0
    setLineWidth 1

    mapM_ (\ (a, b) -> affiche a b) (zip (colonnes,lignes))
    stroke
```

and the error is:

(all 2 at the line with "mapM_"):

```
*   Couldn't match type ‘[(a0, b0)]’ with ‘(Double, Double)’
  Expected type: [b0] -> (Double, Double)
    Actual type: [b0] -> [(a0, b0)]
  In the second argument of ‘mapM_’, namely
    ‘(zip (colonnes, lignes))’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    mapM_ (\ (a, b) -> affiche a b) (zip (colonnes, lignes))


*  Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0]’
              with actual type ‘([Double], [Double])’
  In the first argument of ‘zip’, namely ‘(colonnes, lignes)’
  In the second argument of ‘mapM_’, namely
    ‘(zip (colonnes, lignes))’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    mapM_ (\ (a, b) -> affiche a b) (zip (colonnes, lignes))
```

I also have an other question : please confirm me that if a function returns the type "Render()" then all the statements inside it should return a value of this type.
thanks

Comment: There is no reason to write floating point literals in the form `300.0` in Haskell; `300/4` works just fine. It would make sense to give `colonnes` and `lignes` the correct _signature_ though, i.e. `[Double]`.

Comment: Since you already seem to be familiar with list comprehensions, you might prefer droping `affiche` altogether and just using `sequence_ [C.rectangle a b 1 1 | a <- colonnes, b <- lignes, mandelbrot a b]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` construct in Haskell doesn't work like in other languages: it's actually the equivalent to the ternary *conditional operator* that's `? :` in C-like languages. That means, if you use `if ... then`, you *must* aways also have an `else` branch.

The reason: Haskell isn't imperative; you don't write out *what should be done* but *what the result should be*. In an imperative language, you can *do nothing*, but in Haskell you always need to specify *some* result.

Now, a monadic `do` block of course is basically an imperative embedded language. Here, you *can* just specify that a local result should be the [no-op](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) action, to achieve that nothing is done at that point:

```
    affiche a b = do 
      if mandelbrot a b then 
        C.rectangle a b 1 1
        return ()   -- note: `return` isn't needed here
       else
        return ()
      return ()  -- nor here
```

A shorter way of writing this would be with the [`when`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:when) combinator, which is basically if-then-else with a `return ()` in the else-branch:

```
    affiche a b = when (mandelbrot a b) $ C.rectangle a b 1 1
```

There's another problem with your code:

```
  in 
    map (\t -> t/300*4-2) colonnes      -- number list
    map (\t -> t/200*4-2) lignes        -- number list
    map affiche (zip (colonnes,lignes)) -- list of `Render ()` actions
    stroke                              -- `Render ()` action
```

There, you just write out a couple of expressions of completely different types. You can't do that! What is Haskell supposed to *do* with these expressions?

Well, evidently you want to *execute a sequence of actions*. Hence you need `do` again!

```
  in do
    ...
```

But these lists you get from `map (\t -> t/300*4-2) colonnes` are not actions at all. You can't execute them, just *evaluate* them. In this case, apparently you want `colonnes` to be the *result* of mapping that function over the list `[0..299]`. Well, then why don't you specify this right away?

```
    colonnes = map (\t -> t/300*4-2) [0..299]
    lignes = map (\t -> t/200*4-2) [0..199]
```

or, why not as a list comprehension

```
    colonnes = [ t/300*4-2 | t<-[0..299] ]
    lignes = [ t/200*4-2) t<-[0..199] ]
```

Finally, you need to map `affiche` over the lists. That's in fact a “monadic action map”. The function for this is [`mapM_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:mapM_), not `map`.

```
    colonnes = [ t/300*4-2 | t<-[0..299] ]
    lignes = [ t/200*4-2) t<-[0..199] ]
  in
    mapM_ affiche $ zip colonnes lignes
    stroke
```

Almost there, but not quite. If the signature of `affiche` would take a *tuple* of two numbers (you get such tuples from `zip`), then this would work. However, `affiche a b = do` means the function is [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) (as is customary in Haskell, in particularly also for `zip`!). You can easily undo that though

```
    mapM_ (uncurry affiche) $ zip colonnes lignes
```

but in this specific case I would actually recommend instead defining

```
    affiche :: (Float,Float) -> C.Render ()
    affiche (a,b) = when (mandelbrot a b) $ C.rectangle a b 1 1
```

because `a` and `b` really belong together, forming a single coordinate specification.

There's one more problem: you've used `Float` numbers here. Well... [it doesn't really make sense to do that, in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/Floating_point). At any rate, [`rectangle`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cairo-0.13.1.1/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Cairo.html#v:rectangle) needs `Double` as arguments, so either switch both `affiche` and `mandelbrot` to also take `Double`, or convert `a` and `b` before passing to `rectangle`:

```
    affiche :: (Float,Float) -> C.Render ()
    affiche (a,b) = when (mandelbrot a b)
                  $ C.rectangle (realToFrac a) (realToFrac b) 1 1
```

Oh, and yet another thing: I don't think `zip` does the right thing here. But... figure this out yourself...

Comment: There's still the issue of the calls to `map`. I'm not sure if that's something you want to address in this answer.

Comment: Ah. `zip` is of course also curried, i.e. you need `zip colonnes lignes`, not `zip (colonnes, lignes)`. How did I miss this? (But as I said, `zip` is probably not the right thing anyway, here... test it out and see.)

Comment: Since you already point out that Haskell is not an imperative language, I believe there's not much use in talking about 'statements' (e.g. `if statement`).

Comment: @leftaroundabout thanks, the compiler does not raise errors no more, but...the mandelbrot set doesn't appear. I will create an other topic for this error.

Comment: Ah, but a diagonal line does appear, won't it?

Comment: @leftaroundabout hello, it works now but I am facing to a new challenge : pls have a look at #haskell and gtk : how to draw points as soon as they are computed# : it's the new question I submitted